# Inserting a JSON file inside an Excel, following my structure

Tags: python, json, openpyxl

I'm trying to dump this JSON file inside my Excel file I made with Openpyxl.

Here is an example of my JSON file:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "url": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/p-161271/",
    "titolo": "Appartamenti e Attici di nuova costruzione in vendita a Roma",
    "prezzo": "da \u20ac 165.000 - \u20ac 254.000",
    "citta": "Roma",
    "zona": "Infernetto",
    "via": "Via Croviana, 89",
    "tipologia": "",
    "superficie": "",
    "posti_auto": "",
    "piano": "",
    "piani_edificio": "",
    "balcone": 0,
    "cantina": 0,
    "terrazza": 0,
    "giardino_privato": 0,
    "taverna": 0,
    "esposizione_esterna": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "url": "https://www.immobiliare.it/annunci/88266101/",
    "titolo": "Trilocale via Scigliano, Morena, Roma",
    "prezzo": "\u20ac 260.000\u20ac 280.000(-7,1%)",
    "citta": "Roma",
    "zona": "Morena",
    "via": "Via Scigliano",
    "tipologia": "Appartamento",
    "superficie": "101 m\u00b2",
    "posti_auto": "",
    "piano": "1\u00b0",
    "piani_edificio": "1 piano",
    "balcone": 1,
    "cantina": 0,
    "terrazza": 0,
    "giardino_privato": 0,
    "taverna": 0,
    "esposizione_esterna": 1
  },
```

And here is a screenshot of where the data needs to end:[image: Excel File]

Basically what I'm finding difficult is telling exactly where to go and place the data. I thought about the process and its should basically go in this order:

- For every ID object, the data goes as 1 per column until it reaches the next ID.

Here is my code:

```
    riga_dump, colonna_dump = 3, 2

    for value in self.json:
        cell = scheda_1.cell(row=riga_dump, column=colonna_dump)
        cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
        cell.font = Font(color='00000000')
        cell.value = value
        colonna_dump += 1
        if colonna_dump == 17:
            riga_dump += 1
```

Problem is, in this way I'm trying to place an entire ID object inside one cell...

Comment: You just need to convert the JSON items into lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if understand your problem correctly (since I see no problem at all and this seems frustrating, especially given the absence of answers). So probably all you need is to add the outer loop to iterate objects. Something like this:

```
riga_dump, colonna_dump = 3, 2

for obj in json:

    for value in obj:
        cell = scheda_1.cell(row=riga_dump, column=colonna_dump)
        cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
        cell.font = Font(color='00000000')
        cell.value = value
        colonna_dump += 1

    riga_dump += 1
    colonna_dump = 2 # or = 0 ? it's hard to tell from your screenshot
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Also, sorry for my late answer, I'll try this tomorrow mornign and I hope it works. Again, thanks!

Comment: Ok, this works, I couldn't wait to try it, though the one problem is that it gets the key and not the value associated to the key, any idea on how to select only the value?

Comment: Well, it's need to change `cell.value = value` to `cell.value = obj[value]`

Comment: This worked, thanks and I'll mark the answer as correct, you really got me a good lesson on JSON in Python, thanks!